# iOS apps and Google Geocoding API

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, core-location, google-geocoder

I'd like to make use of the Google Geocoding Json api (`http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false`) in my iOS app, but I don´t find if the use of this URL has any restrictions and/or this may be rejected when submitted to App Store.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @QuangHà If I'd find any restriction in using such URL (number of calls limit or something like that), and if Apple may reject an app using this service

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions, read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) in particular the Usage Limits and Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions.

This would not be a problem for the app store.  Apple does not restrict what geocode service you can use.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is you are using Non-secure URL to access google geocode API, which will give no data from Google side.

Second thing, Apple has rollout some guideline during WWDC 2016 to use always secure URL if you want to access it withing from APP please check out [the link](https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/) so there are chances about maybe they found you are using non-secure link to communicate with web service, and your application will be rejected from Apple.

We are using Google GeoCode and reverse Geocode API within Unity using C# HTTPWebRequest class with the Secure link. our app pass out through Apple Review